# How can I achieve the SQL equivalent of "Like" using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can I use regular expressions and isin() to perform the SQL LIKE statement ?

I have a dataframe with the following values:

```
my_list=['U*']
df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','Germany','China']})
df['node']=0
print(df)
df.loc[df['countries'].isin(my_list),'node']=100
print(df)
```

I wanted the node values for US and UK to be changed to 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) or [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for start of strings for condition:

```
print (df[df.countries.str.startswith('U')])
  countries
0        US
1        UK
```

Or:

```
print (df[df.countries.str.contains('^U')])
  countries
0        US
1        UK
```

EDIT:

```
df['node'] = np.where(df.countries.str.startswith('U'), 100, 0)
print (df)
  countries  node
0        US   100
1        UK   100
2   Germany     0
3     China     0
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way I can use the isin function and pass it a regular expression ? I am updating a data frame and needed this functionality

Comment: Hmmm, why is necessary use `isin` ? `isin` works only with `values : iterable, Series, DataFrame or dictionary` - [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: **bold**
#Required Functionality
my_list=['U*']
df=pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','Germany','China']})
df['node']=0
print(df)
df.loc[df['countries'].isin(my_list),'node']=100
print(df)

Comment: Hmmm, I add answer for it. But still isin is not necessary.

Comment: And for multiple values is possible use `df['node'] = np.where(df.countries.str.contains('^{}'.format('|^'.join(['U', 'G']))), 100,0)`

Comment: When I run two commands, why does it overwrite rows ? I was expecting this code to have the node replaced with 100 for all rows

#Required functionality
my_list=["U","Ch*","30-60"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','Germany','China']})
df['node']=0
print(df)
df['node'] = np.where(df.countries.str.match('^{}'.format('|^'.join(my_list))), 100,0)
print (df)
df['node'] = np.where(~df.countries.str.match('^{}'.format('|^'.join(my_list))), 100,0)
print(df)

Answer (score 0):

To account for the list or isin part, you can play with the regexp:

```
countries = ['U.*', 'Ch.*']
countries_regexp = '^({})$'.format('|'.join(countries))
df[df.countries.str.match(countries_regexp)]
```

Note: [match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match) is stricter than [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) but both work in that case (though contains gives you a warning for matching groups in case your intent to get the actual groups).

Or check the match against each element of your `countries` list and combine the resulting filters:

```
filters = [df.countries.str.match(pat) for pat in countries]
df[reduce(operator.or_, filters, False)]
```

the first one is faster:

```
(1) 538 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
(2) 1.3 ms ± 42.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: code works on my side. There's a problem in the regex of your question: it should be `'U.*'` and not `'U*'`. Did you try with my regex?